# chmod 777 security leak on a log directory?

Tags: php, logging, permissions, chmod

I'm hosting my website in a shared server, so my options are limited. For instance, I don't have access to [the `exec` function](http://www.php.net/exec).

My problem is that my very easy `addLog` PHP function needs rights to write into log files. I had read in another post that the PHP user is *usually* assimilated as "others" in the traditional UNIX owner-group-other permission scheme.

However, since I built my own `www` structure, I was thinking of letting my `./log` directory's permissions be set to `777` so the script could write to the necessary logs.

The application only needs to be able to write to the log files; no read or execute permissions are necessary. (I don't even know what they are when it comes to UNIX permissions) Additionally, I am not storing any database information in the logs; I may, however, store stack traces.

- **Is there a security risk to set the log directory's permissions to `777`?**
  There's nothing in this folder except logs.
- **Are the read and execute rights necessary on this directory?**
  I only really need to write (append) into the logs.

Comment: That depends on how that shared hosting is set up

Comment: it could be a very bad idea, for example, if the `log` folder is accessible via web, and it allows executing scripts

Comment: @wroniasty: `777` on directory has nothing to do with `it allows executing scripts`. Also - 777 doens't give any additional privileges when you access it through http

Comment: @zerkms, could you detail how the shared hosting setup would impact my decision please?

Comment: @Sebas: that depends on what other hosting users could do. And I'm not sure anyone can guess for sure for your particular case (we don't even know what hosting you use)

Comment: What kind of information do you think would be relevant? The host is unix, but for the rest of the involved technology I guess I would have to investigate

Comment: @zerkms 777 allows everyone (including the webserver user) to write to the directory, opening the possibility of someone uploading and executing a script on the server side

Comment: @zerkms so how does that relate to : `777 doens't give any additional privileges when you access it through http` ?

Comment: @wroniasty: it relates to: "it could be a very bad idea, for example, if the log folder is accessible via web, and it allows executing scripts". 777 is a bad idea in any way, regardless it is accessible from outside or not

Comment: @zerkms, is a 703 more restrictive regarding to exuction of malicious scripts? this is actually one of my concerns from the beginning.

Comment: @zerkms, I totally agree with you, executing scripts is just an example of the evil things that come with 777.

Comment: @Sebas - 703 IS more restrictive, but IMO it's still not restrictive enough.

Answer (score 3):

Remember that it is possible that an application error could contain database login information, query strings, as well as file structure of your application. There may be certain files that you have hidden from users and robots, but are still in the document root.  By allowing anybody (777) on the shared environment to view the log (any) files you open yourself to more risk.

If PHP is writing the log it should also be able to read the log, in theory. Bottom line is making the file owner the same user that will be writing to the file. Then use appropriate permissions.

Of course if you are not concerned with anything on your site being secure, and there are no DB connections, it really doesn't matter.

Really depends on the shared environment. I have seen poorly set up shared hosting where users are able to FTP traverse and view others files/folders. 777 is not a good idea on shared hosting. (Better to be safe, than sorry)

Comment: It's terribly wrong answer. Filesystem permissions have not much to do with availability through http

Comment: Yes, you are right, but on shared hosting it is could be WIDE open to other users on the box.

Comment: it is opened, so what? And **HOW** it is related to DB?!?

Comment: If error messages are logged it could contain DB connection strings, or SQL statements ran by the scripts.

Comment: and how 777 related to it? So let's say I just made one of my directories 777 at tvfedor.ru (it's my project for fun). So, what could you do? What the knowledge that some of directories is 777 could give to you?

Comment: Really depends on the shared environment.  I have seen poorly set up shared hosting where users are able to FTP traverse and view others files/folders. 777 is not a good idea on shared hosting. (Better to be safe, than sorry)

Comment: See your logs, check DB credentials, connect to DB, delete all your entries... in worst case. Or see your application errors - the perfect source to test various hacking attempts and see responses. Dev logs should NEVER EVER be made public.

Comment: @Adam Culp: you better put your last thoughts to the answer - they make more sense than the current answer's revision. Because 777 and opened to indexing - are just different not related things

Comment: @Tomasz, what if I don't allow any "read" permission, and I don't store any DB credentials?

Comment: I am not sure you will be able to write without reading. (I truly don't know, but of what use is a log you can't read.) I guess the most sensitive info would be DB credentials, depending on what files you are storing, but remember that even DB structure can be as dangerous as credentials in the right hands.

Comment: I download the logs and watch them on my pcs; i just tried 703 rights and this is working, I guess this is better than 777...